# Where are descriptions of attributes in datafiles on naturalearthdata.com?

Tags: geotools, natural-earth

I have downloaded some datafiles from naturalearthdata.com site.

For example, `ne_50m_admin_0_countries` feature source contains dozenz of attributes with names like `scalerank`, `level`, `mapcolor7`, `mapcolor8`, `mapcolor13` and so on.

It is possible to guess the meaning of some of them but others are mysterious.

Is there any description for these attribute names?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a favourite question on Natural Earths forum ;-)

A basic introduction is posted here:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/forums/topic/thematic-codes/

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/forums/topic/are-the-attributes-documented/

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/forums/topic/what-does-mapcolor-mean-in-ne_10m_admin_0_countries/

The mapcolor fields can be used to colour the countries in a way that adjacent countries do not share the same colour. You can choose between 7, 8 and 13 colours which you can select on your own.